# How can I forbid javascript scripts?

Tags: javascript, api, google-chrome-extension

How can I forbid/stop an extension in my website?

I have videos in my website and would like to have an idea on how I can stop download feature.

Comment: You can exploit a bug in Chrome, which is likely to remain for the next few decades judging by the almost non-existent progress on hundreds of reported extensions-related bugs. Create an `iframe` with `src="javascript:0"` and serve the videos inside. This is effectively the same as `about:blank`

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking - you can't.

You can't dictate what browser extensions will or will not work on your site.

Neither can you completely forbid video downloads.

I mean, if a user can *perceive* content of any type, she will be able to **copy** this content (text/video/sound).

You can only try to make it harder, but you can't really protect it against a skilled user in the browser.

One popular way is to make content visible only for certain users (subscribed, logged-in, etc.).

Comment: Hi Igor, Thanks for your answer, I understand that but there are different ways for doing it. I have found an article, in the article written that if in the website will be used encrypted video streaming it can help me.  Please see this: https://www.dacast.com/blog/aes-video-encryption/

Comment: Yes, you are right, I can't protect my website completely, but will be good If I can forbid it partially. Do you have any suggestion for doing that?

Comment: @Miqayel Hey! Well, I'm unaware of any robust way. As far as I understand, this article tells about some ways to prevent "leaking" to third parties rather than to protect it against the final user.

Comment: @Miqayel just make it impossible to download videos via user interface. That's all that I can suggest without seeing any code & without knowing how you serve the video.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Igor. Thanks for your time. I'll try to make it impossible!